# Clicking on a chat flag notification in IE10 doesn't pop up the dialog to act on the flag

Tags: bug, status-declined, flags, chat

**Browser:** IE 10.0.9200.16384 (desktop mode, not modern)

**OS:** Windows 8 Enterprise

**When:** About 13:30 UTC on the 22nd of March 2013

In chat, the little blue chat flag notification popped up on my avatar. I clicked it a few times, but was never presented with the popup to actually preview the offending comment and vote on it. After a few seconds, the notification went away (likely because it was handled by others).

Chat flags are infrequent enough that I'm not waiting for another to see if I can repro before posting, so if it's a one-time client-side quirk, then my bad!

Answer (score 1):

I think that after almost three years, we can close this as obsolete. We do not support that version of IE anymore.

Does this happen with newer versions?